# Segmentation Violation when passing pointer to base in CPPYY

Tags: c++, python-3.x, cppyy

The following code is a minimal example of this strange error.

 The constructor of `bar` takes a pointer to the base class `BaseFoo` as argument.

 When I tried to make a list of **three** `BaseFoo` pointers and create a `Bar` object for each of them, I get segmentation error.

 However, if I only make **two** `BaseFoo` I seldom get any error.

 Can someone explain why?

```
import cppyy

cppyy.cppdef(r'''
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct BaseFoo {
    BaseFoo() = default;

    virtual ~BaseFoo() {}
};

struct Foo: public BaseFoo {
    Foo() {}

    static shared_ptr<Foo> make() { return make_shared<Foo>(); }

    virtual ~Foo() {}
};

class Bar {
private:
    const shared_ptr<BaseFoo> foo;
public:
    explicit Bar(const shared_ptr<BaseFoo> &foo): foo(foo) {}

    static shared_ptr<Bar> make(const shared_ptr<BaseFoo> &param) {
        return make_shared<Bar>(param);
    }
};
''')

from cppyy.gbl import Foo, Bar


def get_params():
    params = cppyy.gbl.std.vector['shared_ptr<BaseFoo>']([
        Foo.make(), Foo.make(), Foo.make()
    ])
#     params = cppyy.gbl.std.vector['shared_ptr<BaseFoo>']([
#         Foo.make(), Foo.make()
#     ])
    
    return [p for p in params]

for p in get_params():
    Bar.make(p)
```

Comment: `shared_ptr<BaseFoo>` will call the wrong destructor when it points to a `Foo`.

Comment: @DrewDormann Thanks for pointing that out I just added the virtual destructors, it looks like the issue still exists.

Comment: Platform and version? Code runs fine for me (Linux, cppyy 2.4.1) for any number of `Foo.make()`.

Comment: Ahhh I'm using `1.6.1`. Let me try updating this and retest it

Comment: @WimLavrijsen I just upgraded `cppyy`, this issue disappears. Thanks!

Comment: However, I'm still interested in knowing what's in `cppyy` `1.6.1` that causes it.